# Data encryption from WinDev to Java

Tags: java, encryption, windev

I have two applications:

- Windev app which generates a secret key.
- Java app which receives and uses the key.

I want to encrypt the key in Windev and decrypt it in my java application.

Now Windev supports these encryption types: cryptAnsi, cryptFast, cryptRC516, cryptSecure.
More details [here.](http://doc.pcsoft.fr/en-us/?3024014&name=Crypt)

I want to know Which of these encryptions can be decrypted in Java.

Comment: Based on the windev link you provided, perhaps you should download the wd160java.jar file and include that in your project?

Answer (score 0):

The default of 'cryptFast' that implements the Blowfish algorithm can be used with the [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) encryption library.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the same library to generate and use your key. You can use a java library in your windev application using [javaload()](http://doc.pcsoft.fr/en-US/?3048001&name=javaload_function) function.
Doing this, you will add a new dependency (jvm.dll) to your windev application but you will be sure of what type of encryption is used. I have already tried to get information from pcsoft(windev editor) about it but never got it.